# Update (increment) array's object field or create (if not exists) whole document - MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, insert-update

I'd like to increment some field in nested array or if document not exists, or object in array - create them.

Example of existing filled document:

```
{
  _id: "some_id_1",
   my_objects: [
   {
     objectId: "abc",
     fieldA: -5, 
     fieldB: 44
   },
   {
     objectId: "123",
     fieldA: -6, 
     fieldB: 88
   }
  ]
}
```

To increment `fieldA` in array's object with id `abc` I can write query:

```
colection.updateOne(
{$and:[
   {$eq:[_id, "some_id_1"]}, 
   {$eq:[objectId, "abc"]}
]},
   {$inc:{"my_objects.$.fieldA":1}}
)
```

and it works.

The problem is when this collection is empty or `my_objects` is empty. If document doesn't exist I'd like to create the document with object in array . Or if document exists but array `my_objects` is empty I'd like to add object with `fieldA` to array.

```
///documnet after single update query. Is it possible?
{
   _id: "some_id_1",
   my_objects: [
     {
       objectId: "abc",
       fieldA: 1, 
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can use Updates with Aggregation Pipeline - for performing various checks and corresponding updates.